# Cannot Run NodeJS scripts with ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer

### Objective

I have my scripts written separately, in `project/api` folder. Lets take `test.js` for example and I am exporting it via `module.exports`, Now I run my electron window, and create a JavaScript file with `button id="startTask"` function `onclick()`. Now I want to execute this `test.js` on the button click.

But it does not work.

### test.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const exec_path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
const fs = require('fs');

async function test(){
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: exec_path})
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    if(fs.existsSync('./data/cookies.json')){
        let cookie = fs.readFileSync('./data/cookies.json')
        let cookieParsed = JSON.parse(cookie)
        await page.setCookie(...cookieParsed)
        await page.goto(BASE_URL, {waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle0'], timeout: 0});
    }else{
        await browser.close();
        console.log('No Cookies found')
    }
}

module.exports = test;
```

### HTML + JS

```
//This is located in my 'project/src' folder

//This is button.html


<button id="startTask" class = "btn btn-primary"> Start </button>

<script src="./button.js"></script>



//This is button.js

const test = require('../api/test');

document.getElementById("startTask").onclick = () =>{
    try{

       console.log("working")
       test();
    
    } catch(err){

        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

### This is the output on console

[image: Electron Error]

Only the "working" is printed on the console, the Puppeteer-script does not execute.

Thank You for Help!

### Update (3 hours after question posted)

I tried a normal program with `test.js`

#### test.js (simple program)

```
async function test(){
    console.log("Great Cool Awesome")
}
module.exports = test;
```

### Output

[image: Electron Output on simple program]

For a simple program it executes the script, but I need puppeteer for my program.

What is the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
//In button.js

const { remote } = require("electron");
const test = remote.require('./api/test');

document.getElementById("startTask").addEventListener('click', runScript)

async function runScript(){
    try{
        console.log('Running The Script')
        await test();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not awaiting the `test` call so most likely the program runs to an end before it has a chance to start the web page in the function.

Change code to:

```
document.getElementById("startTask").onclick = async () =>{
    try{

       console.log("working")
       await test();
    
    } catch(err){

        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: On first try it opened a black chrome window, then I tried again and it went back to nothing, it just shows working on the console but does not launch the other script.